# WP_User_Query with multiple keys in meta_query not giving correct order

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a WP_User_Query that my goal is to get a sorted list. Firstly, it should be alphabetically-sorted. Then, there is a flag `accepting_new_patients` that I'd like to move them to the top. So, in the end, I want a sorted list of alphabetical people accepting patients, and then the remainder that aren't to also be sorted alphabetically. This is what I have (and from the docs and other posts it seems this is correct):

```
$args = [
        'meta_query' => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'last_name_clause' => ['key' => 'last_name', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
            'accepting_new_patients_clause' => ['key' => 'accepting_new_patients', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
            ['key' => 'name', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
            ['key' => 'headshot', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
            ['relation' => 'OR', 
                ['key' => 'title', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
                ['key' => 'tel', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
                ['key' => 'email', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!=']
            ],
            ['relation' => 'OR', ['key' => 'delist', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'], ['key' => 'delist', 'value' => 0, 'compare' => '=']]
        ],
        'orderby' => ['last_name_clause' => 'ASC', 'accepting_new_patients_clause' => 'DESC'],
    ];
    $therapists = new WP_User_Query($args);
    $results = $therapists -> get_results();
    return $results;
```

With this code, the list *is* being returned alphabetically, but the people accepting new patients are still just in their original alphabetical order. How do I make it to where it will show the people accepting patients first, and then the people not accepting?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the second that I post a question, I figure it out. Here is the answer in case anybody encounters the same issue I had:

```
$args = [
        'meta_query' => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'last_name_clause' => ['key' => 'last_name', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
            'accepting_new_patients_clause' => ['key' => 'accepting_new_patients', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
            'board_member_clause' => ['key' => 'board_member', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
            ['key' => 'name', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
            ['key' => 'headshot', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
            ['relation' => 'OR', 
                ['key' => 'title', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
                ['key' => 'tel', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='],
                ['key' => 'email', 'value' => '', 'compare' => '!=']
            ],
            ['relation' => 'OR', ['key' => 'delist', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'], ['key' => 'delist', 'value' => 0, 'compare' => '=']]
        ],
        'orderby' => ['accepting_new_patients_clause' => 'DESC', 'last_name_clause' => 'ASC'],
    ];
    $therapists = new WP_User_Query($args);
    return $therapists -> get_results();
```